# What does "permalink to this answer" mean, actually?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, answers, permalink

I have seen at the bottom of either a question or answer a link called `link`. When I mouse over it, the tooltip says `Permalink to this question` or `Permalink to this answer`.

What does this actually mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Permalink" is a [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of the words "permanent" and "link".

It's a fancy Web-2.0 word for links that will not change with time, so you can use them to link to their targets from various sources without worrying about them moving on you.

Granted, the term "permanent link" would be more accessible to non-native English speakers. Atwood's Angels should fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Though "permanent link" would have been more accessible for non-native English speakers, neither did I know what was a permamnent link. I now know because of you. Thanks! =)

Comment: @Will: It's actually a fairly common term for sites that can more than one way of viewing the same content. Perhaps "Direct link" would be more meaningful to you?

Comment: @26 years of Welbog: Yes, "Direct link" is more meaningful to me. =)